# Pick color from Image in ImageView [Problem]

Tags: android, color-picker

I'm making an app in which I pick image using Camera/Gallery Intent and then set it to ImageView. After that onTouch on the image(in ImageView) I get Hex, RGB and HSL values of the color of the touched pixel of the image.

This works well for the image imported the first time but when I import image second time and touch on that new image it gives me the color of the previous image.

**Here is my code:**

```
package com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.colorslab;
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.NumberFormat;

public class PickFromImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mImageView;
    TextView mResultTv;
    ImageButton mCopyBtn, mShareBtn;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    View view;

    Uri image_uri;

    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE = 1000;
    private static final int IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE = 1001;
    private static final int PERMISSION_READ_STORAGE_CODE = 1002;
    private static final int PERMISSION_WRITE_STORAGE_CODE = 1003;
    private static final int PERMISSION_CAMERA_CODE = 1004;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_pick_from_image);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setTitle("Color Picker");
            actionBar.setSubtitle("Pick color from Image");
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }

        mImageView =findViewById(R.id.imageIv);
        mResultTv = findViewById(R.id.restultTv);
        mCopyBtn = findViewById(R.id.copyBtn);
        mShareBtn = findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);
        view = findViewById(R.id.colorView);

        mImageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mImageView.buildDrawingCache(true);

        mImageView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                    bitmap = mImageView.getDrawingCache();
                    int pixel = bitmap.getPixel((int)event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

                    int r = Color.red(pixel);
                    int g = Color.green(pixel);
                    int b = Color.blue(pixel);

                    int color = Color.TRANSPARENT;

                    Drawable background = view.getBackground();
                    if (background instanceof ColorDrawable)
                        color = ((ColorDrawable) background).getColor();

                    view.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r,g,b));
                    mResultTv.setText("HEX: "+ String.format("#%06X", 0xFFFFFF & color)
                            +"\nRGB: "+ r +", "+ g +", "+ b
                            +"\nHSL: "+ rgbToHsl(r,g,b));
                }
                return true;
            }
        });


        mCopyBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String data = mResultTv.getText().toString();

                ClipboardManager cb = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
                cb.setText(data);
                Toast.makeText(PickFromImageActivity.this, "Copied...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        mShareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String data = mResultTv.getText().toString();

                Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
                sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, data);
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
            }
        });

    }

    private String rgbToHsl(int r, int g, int b) {
        final float rf = r / 255f;
        final float gf = g / 255f;
        final float bf = b / 255f;

        final float max = Math.max(rf, Math.max(gf, bf));
        final float min = Math.min(rf, Math.min(gf, bf));
        final float deltaMaxMin = max - min;

        float h, s;
        float l = (max + min) / 2f;

        if (max == min) {
            // Monochromatic
            h = s = 0f;
        } else {
            if (max == rf) {
                h = ((gf - bf) / deltaMaxMin) % 6f;
            } else if (max == gf) {
                h = ((bf - rf) / deltaMaxMin) + 2f;
            } else {
                h = ((rf - gf) / deltaMaxMin) + 4f;
            }

            s = deltaMaxMin / (1f - Math.abs(2f * l - 1f));
        }

        h = (h * 60f) % 360f;
        s = s*100;
        l = l*100;

        NumberFormat formH = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        formH.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        formH.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        String formattedH = formH.format(h);

        NumberFormat formS = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        formS.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        formS.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        String formattedS = formS.format(s);

        NumberFormat formL = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
        formL.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        formL.setMaximumFractionDigits(0);
        String formattedL = formL.format(l);

        return ""+ formattedH +", "+ formattedS +"%, "+ formattedL +"%";
    }

    public void pickCamera(){
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "New Picture");
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "From Camera");
        image_uri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, image_uri);
        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE);

    }

    public void pickGallery(){
        //intent to pick image
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        intent.setType("image/*");
        startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).setVisible(false);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_about) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutActivity.class));
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_rate) {
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.colorslab")));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.colorslab")));
            }
            return true;
        } else if (id == R.id.action_more) {
            try {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6868537621115215530")));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/dev?id=6868537621115215530")));
            }
            return true;
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_share) {
            Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
            String shareBody = "\"Colors Lab\" contains important tools such as Popular Colors, Pick Color from color platte, Pick Color from Image, Convert Color from and to Hex, RGB, HSL.:\n https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.blogspot.atifsoftwares.colorslab";
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
            sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBody);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_camera) {
            //check runtime permission
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED ||
                        checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    //permission not granted, request it.
                    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.CAMERA, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                    //show popup for runtime permission
                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_WRITE_STORAGE_CODE);
                }
                else {
                    //permission already granted
                    pickCamera();
                }
            }
            else {
                //system os is less then marshmallow
                pickCamera();
            }
        }
        else if (id == R.id.action_gallery) {
            //check runtime permission
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M){
                if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED){
                    //permission not granted, request it.
                    String[] permissions = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
                    //show popup for runtime permission
                    requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_READ_STORAGE_CODE);
                }
                else {
                    //permission already granted
                    pickGallery();
                }
            }
            else {
                //system os is less then marshmallow
                pickGallery();
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //handle result of runtime permission
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case PERMISSION_READ_STORAGE_CODE:{
                if (grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    //permission was granted
                    pickGallery();
                }
                else {
                    //permission was denied
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
            case PERMISSION_CAMERA_CODE:{
                if (grantResults.length >0 && grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                    //permission was granted
                    pickCamera();
                }
                else {
                    //permission was denied
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied...!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        }
    }

    //handle result of picked image
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_GALLERY_CODE){
                //set image to image view
                mImageView.setImageURI(data.getData());
            }
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CAMERA_CODE){
                //set image to image view
                mImageView.setImageURI(image_uri);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Screen shot:
[image: Screenshot example]

Comment: try this ImgView.setImageBitmap(null);
ImgView.destroyDrawingCache(); before adding image

Comment: Thanks you its working perfect now
you may add it as answer so I accept it as final answer

Comment: mark as solution my answer i wrote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add before adding the image...

```
mImageView.setImageBitmap(null); 
mImageView.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 1):

before adding image
write this piece of code

```
ImgView.setImageBitmap(null); 

ImgView.destroyDrawingCache();
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get color, first you have to get the pixel which is clicked by user
To get a pixel, you must get the bitmap on a canvas and then read the RGB values of that clicked pixel
Below code will help you do so

```
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

 int pixel = bitmap.getPixel(x,y); // x and y are coordinates
    int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
    int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
    int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
    if(pixel == Color.RED){
           // color is red
        }
```

You can use multiple conditions or a logic to create RGB code from above values.